# Azure mobile node.js backend deploy port issue

Tags: android, node.js, azure, mobile, backend

I'm new on node.js and azure.
I want to develop a mobile app which insert and select data in a table.
For the android part - client side I use the code from  [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/android).
For the node.js part - server side I use the code from the same repository [this code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/backend/node/TodoSample)

When I deploy the node.js project on azure I give an error:
[image: see picture]

I have this message if a use any code for mobile node.js.

In Container diag, the problem is at PORT:

> Check your Application Settings to make sure that the PORT setting of your container is correct. You can also view Application Logs to determine if there was a wrong PORT set.

In application logs the port is 8080:

> ERROR - Container antaresmobilejs_0_7b069d42 for site antaresmobilejs
>   has exited, failing site start  ERROR - Container
>   antaresmobilejs_0_7b069d42 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080,
>   failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

In my node.js code, I set the port to 8080, but I don't find the port settings in application settings.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the Node.js backend port for Azure Mobile Apps should be set as below if using Express.js.

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

It was introduced in the offical document [`How to use the Mobile Apps Node.js SDK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk), as the figure below.

[image]

It also be coded in the offcal sample code https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/blob/master/backend/node/TodoSample/app.js#L35

The code `process.env.PORT` will read the default port specified by Azure from the environment, and the [`web.config`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/blob/master/backend/node/TodoSample/web.config) file will help node backend app to start up by IIS.

[image]

The real port of API endpoint for client is `80`, because the node app hosted in IIS.